# Oracle - zero iteration count - package procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Can somebody help me to understand the error code :

> **ORA-24333: zero iteration count**

that I encounter sometimes while executing my procedure (in package)?

It's random and I can't find the origin of this issue.

To explain the case : I need to count the number of rows in resultset of several queries.

Application side in secondary thread, call the procedure

```
PROC_COUNTER(p1 IN, p2 IN, Cursor_out OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
```

The procedure PROC_COUNTER contains several procedure calls which fill global temporary tables (on commit preserve rows) like below :

```
PROC_COUNTER(p1 IN, p2 IN, Cursor_out OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS

BEGIN

PROC_1(); -- 1st global temporary table (truncate gtt_1  following by INSERT INTO gtt_1 from v_gtt_1)
PROC_2(); -- 2nde global temporary table (truncate gtt_2  following by INSERT INTO gtt_2 from v_gtt_2)
PROC_3(); -- 3th global temporary table (truncate gtt_3  following by INSERT INTO gtt_3 from v_gtt_3)
PROC_4(); -- 4th global temporary table (truncate gtt_4 following by INSERT INTO gtt_4 from v_gtt_4)


OPEN CURSOR_OUT FOR sSql_ALL; --- sSQL_all is the query to execute


END PROC_COUNTER;
```

sSql_ALL contains 6 subqueries linked by UNION ALL like below :

```
SELECT   'VUE_1' AS VUE, 

    COUNT(distinct TBL_MASTER.seq_TBL_MASTER) AS NBR_LIGNE  

    FROM TBL_MASTER 

    /**/           
    JOIN TBL_1        ON TBL_1.SEQ_TBL_MASTER = TBL_MASTER.SEQ_TBL_MASTER

    /**/
    JOIN TBL_2     ON TBL_2.SEQ_TBL_MASTER = TBL_MASTER.SEQ_TBL_MASTER

    /**/
    LEFT JOIN TBL_3     ON TBL_3.SEQ_TBL_MASTER   = TBL_MASTER.SEQ_TBL_MASTER

    /**/
    JOIN TBL_4_GTT_GTT      ON TBL_4_GTT.SEQ_NG_FONDS      = TBL_MASTER.SEQ_NG_FONDS

    /**/
    LEFT JOIN TBL_5_GTT ON TBL_5_GTT.SEQ_TBL_MASTER = TBL_MASTER.SEQ_TBL_MASTER

    /**/
    LEFT JOIN TBL_6        ON (TBL_6.SEQ_DEVISE_BASE = TBL_MASTER.SEQ_DEVICE AND TBL_6.SEQ_DEVISE_CONTRE_VALEUR = 4 )

    /**/
    LEFT JOIN  TBL_7_GTT          ON TBL_7_GTT.SEQ_TBL_MASTER = TBL_MASTER.SEQ_TBL_MASTER

    /**/
    JOIN TBL_8_GTT ON TBL_8_GTT.TRADING_ENTITY = TBL_2.ENTITY_RATTACHEMENT

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT   'VUE_2' AS VUE, COUNT(distinct TBL_MASTER.seq_TBL_MASTER) AS NBR_LIGNE  
                               FROM TBL_MASTER 
    /**/           
    JOIN TBL_1        ON TBL_1.SEQ_TBL_MASTER = TBL_MASTER.SEQ_TBL_MASTER

    /**/
    JOIN TBL_2     ON TBL_2.SEQ_TBL_MASTER = TBL_MASTER.SEQ_TBL_MASTER

    /**/
    LEFT JOIN TBL_3     ON TBL_3.SEQ_TBL_MASTER   = TBL_MASTER.SEQ_TBL_MASTER

    /**/
    JOIN TBL_4_GTT      ON TBL_4_GTT.SEQ_NG_FONDS      = TBL_MASTER.SEQ_NG_FONDS

    /**/
    LEFT JOIN TBL_5_GTT ON TBL_5_GTT.SEQ_TBL_MASTER = TBL_MASTER.SEQ_TBL_MASTER

    /**/
    LEFT JOIN TBL_6        ON (TBL_6.SEQ_DEVISE_BASE = TBL_MASTER.SEQ AND TBL_6.SEQ = 4 )

    /**/
    LEFT JOIN  TBL_7_GTT          ON TBL_7_GTT.SEQ_TBL_MASTER = TBL_MASTER.SEQ_TBL_MASTER

    /**/
    JOIN TBL_8_GTT ON TBL_8_GTT.TRADING_ENTITY = TBL_2.ENTITY_RATTACHEMENT

    WHERE TBL_MASTER.STATUS = 'STATUS'
```

NB : ***_GTT is a global temporary table

After several tests, even after have modified the procedure to keep the minimum of code like below: I obtain the error "zero iteration count".

```
PROCEDURE PROC_COUNTER(SEQ_ IN NUMBER, ENT_p IN VARCHAR2 := null, CURSOR_OUT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS

sSql_1                        varchar2(4000); 
sSql_2            varchar2(4000); 
sSql_3   varchar2(4000); 
sSql_4         varchar2(4000); 
sSql_5   varchar2(4000);
sSql_6     varchar2(4000); 
sSql_7                   varchar2(4000); 
sSql_8                 varchar2(4000); 


BEGIN

     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('[START] - PROC_COUNTER');


     OPEN CURSOR_OUT FOR SELECT 'ALL' AS VUE, 999 AS NBR_LIGNE FROM DUAL;


     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('[END] - PROC_COUNTER');   

END PROC_COUNTER;
```

For information, I use native access to oracle and I call my procedure from by application like below :

```
BEGIN
    PKG.PROC_COUNTER(2000, null, :return_value_compteur%CURSOR);
END;
```

Comment: `ORA-24333` is an uncommon bug. You need to provide a reproducible test case so that people can understand what you're doing and how your program could raise such an error. Otherwise there's nothing we can do to help.

Comment: post the value of sSql_ALL

Comment: Thanks for your answer, My post is updated.

Comment: Your last example (standalone PROC_COUNTER procedure) works for me when I remove '%CURSOR' from the call. Sounds like to reproduce the error we will have to use your application.

Comment: It appears to be related to OCI rather than PL/SQL. [This guy](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=1138) seemed to run into something similar and the fix involved setting the `iters` parameter of `OCIStmtExecute()`. All way over my head as a db guy.

Comment: @William Robertson thanks. How you remove the %CURSOR from the call? Do you know what the error means?

Comment: I just meant variable names can't include the `%` character, so change the name to `:return_value_compteur#cursor`, `:return_value_compteur_cursor`, `:return_value_compteur` or something else valid.

Comment: Regarding the error explanation, follow the link I posted and you'll know as much as I do. It appears that [OCIStmtExecute()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci17msc001.htm#LNOCI17163) returns an error if `iters`=0 for non-`SELECT` statements.

Comment: Ok. But if I remove the %CURSOR from my calling, Oracle returns me the error  "PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROC_COUNTER'

Comment: Oh. I guess I was naively assuming the block was run from a desktop tool, SQL*Plus etc but I see you did say it's in your application. In that case it's probably a valid construct in whatever language framework you are developing in. I have no idea what that is except that it appears to use OCI. Sorry.

Comment: If I create a single procedure which calls procedures from the the package. It looks good.  Interesting thing ?!

Comment: So what happens if you adjust the parameters to OCIStmtExecute? (Or is that buried layers deep in some framework you can't mess with?)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson i don't understand how use OCIStmtExecute yet.